# Putting together a js file to use in html

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

So I have found this code [here](http://www.hauntednipple.co.uk/?p=16)

This basically lets me pull some data from a php file and place it into a div using jQuery. So everything from the tutorial works fine, but because I am thinking of putting together about 9-10 different links via that code, I thought I put all the function code in a js file and just call the function in html. Just to clarify, I have very minimal understanding of javascript, though I've experience with php.

In a new js file called links.js, I have put 2 different functions which I would like to call from my html

```
function getshow1() {
$('#sidebar').load('show1.php');
}


function getshow2() {
$('#sidebar').load('show2.php');
}
```

then in my html, I src the links.js and for 2 images, I've put this,

```
<a href="javascript:getshow1();"><img src="image1.jpg" /></a>
<a href="javascript:getshow2();"><img src="image2.jpg" /></a>
```

and of course #sidebar doesn't display anything. How could I format the js file so I can just use the above html code to link different php files?

also, if there is a better way of pulling html code from a external file into a div, do let me know!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html:

```
<a href="#" id="show1"><img src="image1.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#" id="show2"><img src="image2.jpg" /></a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#show1').click(function(){
      $('#sidebar').load('show1.php');
    });

    $('#show2').click(function(){
      $('#sidebar').load('show2.php');
    });
});
```

**edit:** added document ready function

Comment: if I placed the jQuery code into the links.js, would it still work?

Comment: usr1 yes , it will work ,make sure that you jquery is included before links.js and have the clicks events wrap around document.ready.

Comment: would it able to pull .html files instead of .php?

Comment: @usr1 , yes it can pull html files also..that will more easy.

Comment: is this `$('#sidebar').load('show2.html')` what you are asking? If so, yes. This will also work.

Comment: @Kyle thanks for the help code! just one more question, because i am trying to pull a list of images which goes into my slideshow div that also uses jQuery, it does not seem to refresh the slideshow code to pull the images in. Would it be possible to start or restart the slideshow function along with with the above code you provided? the slideshow jquery is this:   $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#slider").easySlider({
   });
   });

Comment: @usr are you asking if you can add the slider code to the code that I wrote?

Comment: well the images that I pull from the html file using your code doesnt seem to send the new list of images to the easyslider jquery hence the images staying the same as before. so I was just wondering if it was possible to add the easyslider function to your code so that the new images will be processed with easyslider once I click the links. I hope I'm not confusing the question even more.

Comment: @usr I'm not sure how the easySlider code works so I cannot say for sure what it is you need to do. I would guess and say that you should add `$("#slider").easySlider({});` after each `$('#sidebar').load();` in the code that I wrote.

Comment: that seems to work, though I'll have to tweak with it a bit. Thanks alot for the help!

Comment: @usr No problem. By-the-way, I just looked at the easySlider source code and you will need to call the `easySlider` function each time you alter `#sidebar`.

Comment: so basically do what you said in your previous comment? I tried to load the easyslider function right after the .load code but the images don't seem to get included in the slide. I included the contents from the easyslider.js into the lists.js and still dosen't seem to refresh the slideshow. still working through it.

Comment: @usr Please ask a new question and provide the HTML and CSS for `#sidebar` as well as a the contents of `show1.php` or .html if that's what you are using. Reply with the link and I will take a look at whats going on.

Comment: @Kyle [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209454/using-load-to-populate-div-with-images-for-easy-slider1-7) thats the new question, thanks for helping me out with this.